# How to pass the result of a function pointer as an argument for another function?

Tags: c, struct, function-pointers

Alright, this is my first post ever in StackOverflow, I have TRIED everything for this. So first instruction is that I need to make a function pointer inside a struct. No problems so far with that.

```
typedef struct Function2D {
    float (*Fun2D) (float);
}Function2D;
```

The teacher wants this struct function pointer to multiply a given float number by two. I already did that.

```
int main() 
{
    Function2D Funcion;
    Funcion.Fun2D = Test;
    Funcion.Fun2D(10000);
    return 0;
}
float Test (float n)
{
    n = n*2;
    return n;
}
```

However I the teacher wants to implement another function that returns a Boolean after getting a data type Function2D or the result of the multiplication. **Is there a way to access the result of the function pointer from a struct without hardcoding a value?**

Comment: I don't think I understand the question.  Can you give a pseudocode example of what you have in mind?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Please [edit] and rephrase your question. I don't understand this sentence: *However I the teacher wants to implement another function that returns a Boolean after getting a data type Function2D or the result of the multiplication.*  I'm also not sure I understand the question of the last sentence. Do you mean something like `float result; result = Funcion.Fun2D(10000);`?

Comment: "I have TRIED everything for this" --> that is quite impresive.

Comment: You can access the value returned by a function using a statement like this: `result = function(argument);` It doesn't matter whether `function` is a regular function or a function pointer in a struct or anything else.

Comment: Thanks guys, thing is I was fucking retard. The teacher was asking only to define each function pointer for functions such as `float (*Fun2D) (float);`  as Function2D. Now all I have to figure out is how to access the value returned by the function pointer/function

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then you are asking how to implement a function

- returning a bool that takes a function as an argument

OR

- that takes a structure containing function pointers as an argument.

OR

- that pass the result from a call to a function pointer to another function.

Here is an example all three:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Define the types for the function pointers you need
typedef float (*FloatFunc) (float);
typedef bool (*BoolFunc) (FloatFunc);

// Declare a structure containing each of the function pointer types defined above.
typedef struct StructContainingFunctionPointers {
    FloatFunc FunFloat;
    BoolFunc  FunBool;
} StructContainingFunctionPointers;

// Declare a function of the same type as FloatFunc
float MultiplyBy2(float n)
{
    n = n * 2;
    return n;
}

// Declare a function of the same type as BoolFunc
bool TestIfMultiplyBy2(FloatFunc func)
{
    return func(2) == 4;
}

// Declare a function that takes StructContainingFunctionPointers as an argument
void TestStructContainingFunctionPointers(StructContainingFunctionPointers Rec) {
    // Do a smoke-test of FunFloat
    float result = Rec.FunFloat(10000);
    // Pass the result of Rec.FunFloat to printf()
    printf("Calling FunFloat(10000) returned %.0f.\n", result);
    if (result == 10000 * 2)
        printf("The float function seems to work.\n");
    else
        printf("The float function DOES NOT work.\n");

    // Do a smoke-test of FunBool
    if (Rec.FunBool(Rec.FunFloat))
        printf("The bool function seems to work.\n");
    else
        printf("The bool function DOES NOT work.\n");
}

int main()
{
    // Initialize the record.
    StructContainingFunctionPointers Rec;
    Rec.FunFloat = MultiplyBy2;
    Rec.FunBool = TestIfMultiplyBy2;
    // Test
    TestStructContainingFunctionPointers(Rec);
    // Return success
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output from the program:

```
Calling FunFloat(10000) returned 20000.
The float function seems to work.
The bool function seems to work.
```